# Can't pass choices option to package

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, key-value, class-options

I am trying to make a custom package to contain all my personal macros and a custom class for my personal style. I wanted to pass a keyword argument `notation` which can take a value of `math` or `physics` in order to change notations for different courses I take (For example, in math the complex conjugate is often denoted with a bar, and in physics it's denoted with an asterisk). After playing around and following the answers I got [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706486/weird-error-in-custom-package-instead-of-the-error-i-tried-to-throw/706489#706489). I got these 3 files:

```latex
% demo-pkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demo-pkg}[Demo]

\RequirePackage{xstring}

\DeclareKeys[demo]
{
    notation.choices:nn =
        { physics, math }
        {\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@demo@notation{l_keys_choice_tl}},
    notation.usage = load,
    notation.initial:n = physics
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[demo]

\IfStrEqCase{\@demo@notation}{
    {physics}{}%
    {math}{}%
}[
    \PackageError{demo-pkg}{Invalid notation value: \@demo@notation}
    {Choose value of: physics, math}
]

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\IfStrEqCase{\@demo@notation}{%
{physics}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{{##1}^{\ast}}%
}%
{math}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{\overline{##1}}%
}%
}%

% demo-cls.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{demo-cls}[Demo class]

\DeclareKeys[demo-cls]
{
    notation.choices:nn =
        { physics, math }
        {\PassOptionsToPackage{notation=l_keys_choice_tl}{demo-pkg}}, % <- This seems to cause issues
    notation.usage = load,
    notation.initial:n = physics
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessKeyOptions[demo-cls]
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{demo-pkg}

% main.tex
\documentclass[notation=math]{demo-cls}

\begin{document}
\[ z = x + iy \Longleftrightarrow \Conjugate{z} = x - iy \]
\end{document}
```

Trying to compile this code gives me an error `Key 'demo/notation' accepts only a fixed set of choices.`. When I use the `demo-pkg` directly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notation=math]{demo-pkg}

\begin{document}
\[ z = x + iy \Longleftrightarrow \Conjugate{z} = x - iy \]
\end{document}
```

it compiles fine, and I can switch notations with the package parameter. Passing the parameter from the class to the package seems to cause issues. I tried using `\l_keys_choice_tl`, `\tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl` and surrounding this code block with `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff`. Nothing works. I get the same error. How can I pass the `notation` parameter from the `demo-cls` class to the `demo-pkg` package?

Comment: I wouldn't mix `\ProcessKeyOptions` and `\ProcessOptions` in the same file, use the old mechanism or the new, processing all the options with both mechanisms is bound to lead to weird effects

Comment: Your issue is that you pass the string `l_keys_choice_tl` as the value. That's the name of a parameter in the `expl3` layer of `l3keys`. Instead of `notation=l_keys_choice_tl` use `\ExpandArgs{e}\PassOptionsToPackage{notation=\UseName{l_keys_choice_tl}}{demo-pkg}`. But I have to agree with @DavidCarlisle don't mix `\ProcessKeyOptions` and `\ProcessOptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to forward the `notation=math` from `\documentclass` to your package. The package uses `\ProcessKeyOptions`, so parses the global option list, which contains that option.

And you can use the `\ProcessKeyOptions` mechanism in your class to forward unknown options to `article`. So the only file needing changes is your class:

`demo-cls.cls`:

```
% demo-cls.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{demo-cls}[Demo class]

\DeclareKeys[demo-cls]
  {
    unknown .code = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions[demo-cls]

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{demo-pkg}
```

`demo-pkg.sty`:

```
% demo-pkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demo-pkg}[Demo]

\RequirePackage{xstring}

\DeclareKeys[demo]
{
    notation.choices:nn =
        { physics, math }
        {\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@demo@notation{l_keys_choice_tl}},
    notation.usage = load,
    notation.initial:n = physics
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[demo]

\IfStrEqCase{\@demo@notation}{
    {physics}{}%
    {math}{}%
}[
    \PackageError{demo-pkg}{Invalid notation value: \@demo@notation}
    {Choose value of: physics, math}
]

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\IfStrEqCase{\@demo@notation}{%
{physics}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{{##1}^{\ast}}%
}%
{math}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{\overline{##1}}%
}%
}%
```

`main.tex`:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[notation=math]{demo-cls}

\begin{document}
\[ z = x + iy \Longleftrightarrow \Conjugate{z} = x - iy \]
\end{document}
```

---

I guess a bit of explanation is in order (also in retrospect for my older answer):

`\ExpandArgs` is a macro that gives a high-level interface to fine control over argument expansion. I used that to set your package internal `\@demo@notation` to the value of an L3-variable without using the L3 language directly (so without `\ExplSyntaxOn` or `\ProvidesExplPackage`). This was done by using `\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@demo@notation{l_keys_choice_tl}`, which means: Before using `\let` use two arguments, the first is an unchanged single token (`N`), the second is a braced group that should form a macro by `\csname`. So `\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@demo@notation{l_keys_choice_tl}` is a better readable variant of this low-level construction:

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\@demo@notation\csname l_keys_choice_tl\endcsname
```

I hope this explanation helps on explaining why your

```
\DeclareKeys[demo-cls]
{
    notation.choices:nn =
        { physics, math }
        {\PassOptionsToPackage{notation=l_keys_choice_tl}{demo-pkg}}, % <- This seems to cause issues
    notation.usage = load,
    notation.initial:n = physics
}
```

Didn't work. Because `l_keys_choice_tl` doesn't magically become the real choice value, that was done by `\ExpandArgs`, and would've to be done by similar means here (which my comment suggested).

Comment: It worked. I still don't understand why there is no need to forward the `documentclass` options to the package.
How does my package know to pick them up and how do other packages know not to consume these options?

Comment: @ShaiAvr options provided to `\documentclass` are so-called global options. Unless you use a package/option-parser which explicitly omits them, every option-parser considers them. The mechanism used is usually "if package X knows option Y it should consider/parse it, and remove the consumed option from the list of unused global options if option Y is still on it, otherwise ignore option Y".  `expkv-opt` for instance provides `\ekvoProcessLocalOptions`, which ignores global options, other packages provide similar means.

Comment: Will my package automatically remove these options from the global list after parsing them, or should I do it myself to prevent other packages from accidentally parsing them?

Comment: @ShaiAvr neither, the global option list is exactly that, a global option list.

Comment: I understand. Thank you